# PHP array duplicate add value to that index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

am just trying to fix my problem. Exactly: I have array that has been filled up by database (music playlist). That array contains duplicates what am trying to achieve is (example rows from database):

```
-- ID: 0 | ARTIST: SOMETHING1 | TITLE: SOMETHING1 | TIME: 04:00 | REPEAT: 1 |
-- ID: 1 | ARTIST: SOMETHING2 | TITLE: SOMETHING2 | TIME: 02:40 | REPEAT: 1 |
-- ID: 2 | ARTIST: SOMETHING3 | TITLE: SOMETHING3 | TIME: 03:20 | REPEAT: 1 |
-- ID: 3 | ARTIST: SOMETHING1 | TITLE: SOMETHING1 | TIME: 04:00 | REPEAT: 1 |
-- ID: 4 | ARTIST: SOMETHING1 | TITLE: SOMETHING1 | TIME: 04:00 | REPEAT: 1 |
-- ID: 5 | ARTIST: SOMETHING1 | TITLE: SOMETHING1 | TIME: 04:00 | REPEAT: 1 |
-- ID: 6 | ARTIST: SOMETHING1 | TITLE: SOMETHING1 | TIME: 04:00 | REPEAT: 1 |
```

So those values would be in array now how would I check for those duplicates in that array. If there would be duplicate I'd want to remove that duplicate but leave only one and add +1 to repeat for each duplicate. Example from above rows:

```
-- ID: 0 | ARTIST: SOMETHING1 | TITLE: SOMETHING1 | TIME: 04:00 | REPEAT: 5 |
-- ID: 1 | ARTIST: SOMETHING2 | TITLE: SOMETHING2 | TIME: 02:40 | REPEAT: 1 |
-- ID: 2 | ARTIST: SOMETHING3 | TITLE: SOMETHING3 | TIME: 03:20 | REPEAT: 1 |
```

Am sorry if there is already post but couldn't find way to explain it better.

Comment: Hi Lance, in your example the ID is always zero. It would be a bit easier if you have a definition for what makes each track unique, if not ID then maybe a combination of artist + title?

Comment: @mickadoo ahh yeah sorry I forgot to change it. In database id is set as auto_increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function. Kindly make sure you change the `ARTIST` key to meet your need.

```
function remove_duplicates($playlist){
    $filtered = [];
    foreach($playlist as $music){
        $array_exist = array_filter($filtered, function($val) use ($music) {
            return ($val['ARTIST'] === $music['ARTIST']) && 
                   ($val['TITLE'] === $music['TITLE']);
        });

        if( empty($array_exist) ){
            $filtered[] = $music;
        }else{
            foreach($array_exist as $index => $arr){
                $filtered[$index]['REPEAT'] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $filtered;
}
```

Example

```
$music_playlist = [
    ['ID' => 1, 'ARTIST' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TITLE' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TIME' => '04:00', 'REPEAT' => 1],
    ['ID' => 2, 'ARTIST' => 'SOMETHING2', 'TITLE' => 'SOMETHING2', 'TIME' => '02:40', 'REPEAT' => 1],
    ['ID' => 3, 'ARTIST' => 'SOMETHING3', 'TITLE' => 'SOMETHING3', 'TIME' => '03:20', 'REPEAT' => 1],
    ['ID' => 4, 'ARTIST' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TITLE' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TIME' => '04:00', 'REPEAT' => 1],
    ['ID' => 5, 'ARTIST' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TITLE' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TIME' => '04:00', 'REPEAT' => 1],
    ['ID' => 6, 'ARTIST' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TITLE' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TIME' => '04:00', 'REPEAT' => 1],
    ['ID' => 7, 'ARTIST' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TITLE' => 'SOMETHING1', 'TIME' => '04:00', 'REPEAT' => 1]
];

print_r(remove_duplicates($music_playlist));
```

Comment: seems to work but still artist could be same but title could be different so your function will count only artist duplicates.

Comment: Which column(s) do you want to use to check for duplicates?

Comment: artist and title

Comment: @lance I've updated the function. Kindly try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: unfortunately still same. I have 18 rows with same artist but different title, your function count them into 1 :(

Comment: Maybe your question isn't clear enough. The function works exactly like the example you showed. Please explain what you want to achieve properly.

Comment: So am converting playlist into database, so it does insert duplicates. To get all songs am using array that looks like `array( "artist"=>"ARTIST FROM DB", "title"=>"TITLE FROM DB", "repeat"=>"REPEAT FROM DB)` So am trying get only one row from duplicates but with repeat +1 of all duplicates. Also artist and titles contain symbols and white spaces. Currently am checking it with excel.

Comment: Oh okay. I've updated the function. Kindly change `||` to `&&`. And let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for/foreach loop with every data you have. Then add the new data when something is not there. And put an auto increment on the ID with primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be in PHP and not SQL, then how about:

```
$keys=[];
foreach($rows as $row) {
   $id=$row['ARTIST'].$row['TITLE'];
   if ( !isset($keys[$id]) ) $keys[$id]=$row;
   else {
       $rowX=$keys[$id];
       $rowX['REPEAT']++;
       $keys[$id]=$rowX;
   }
}
```

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8558cf3ae956ac358962bf3c83ecabc299a38af3 for a working example